# How do I change the configuration settings for phpmyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql

.....I want to change the password and other parameters. I am using the lampp stack. In the mysql terminal I know I can do this:

```
   update user set password=PASSWORD("......."), file_priv='Y' where user='root';
    INSERT INTO user (host, user, password, select_priv, max_connections, max_user_connections) 
VALUES ('localhost','webuser',PASSWORD('ohhai'),'Y',1000,1000);
```

How do I do this with phpMyAdmin.

Also assuming I have my data in text files and I have a .sql file to restore the tables how would I do this with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

well you can edit accounts inside phpmyadmin. But you also can import sql files or just run the sql inside phpmyadmin control panel.

Once logged in, say with root. Either upload the file, or run the sql directly in the `sql` tab. Editing users is easy too, click `privileges`

Comment: When i load local infile what path do I specify? ~ refers to the root path but the file is in my desktop